# Sum arrays containing NSStrings which are prices

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring, nsarray

Sorry for asking this, maybe is too stupid. I was searching a lot and couldn't find a way to do it. I have 2 NSArrays. The first one is a little tricky and could have 2 or more prices in each object, prices are separated by a comma inside object. The second one is simpler and has one price assigned in each individual object.

My goal is to sum all the numbers inside each Array and get the total amount of both.

I was dealing with two problems, first one is the fact that each object has a "$" and the other one was mentioned above. Is the fact that firstArray was builded in a way which makes more difficult to work with.

```
NSArray * myFirstArray = ["$ 22, $ 0", "$ 33, $ 666, $ 66, $ 22", "$ 123, $ 123, $ 555"];

NSArray * mySecondArray = ["$ 120", "$ 22", "$ 20", "$ 10", "$ 11", "$ 0", "$ 1234", "$ 3333"];
```

Comment: The arrays contain garbage.  Start by cleaning them up and creating an array of `NSNumber(float)` values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope this may help you!

```
  NSInteger ir = 0;
  NSArray * myFirstArray =[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"$ 22, $ 0", @"$ 33, $ 666, $ 66, $ 22", @"$ 123, $ 123, $ 555", nil];

   for (int i =0; i<myFirstArray.count; i++) {
    NSArray* foo = [[myFirstArray objectAtIndex:i] componentsSeparatedByString: @","];
    NSLog(@"foo %@",foo);
    for (int j =0; j<foo.count; j++) {
        NSString *rest = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[foo objectAtIndex:j]];
        NSString* noSpaces =  [rest stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"$" withString:@""];
        ir = ir +[noSpaces integerValue];
    }
}

NSLog(@"myFirstArray :: %ld",(long)ir);
```

Similarly for secondArray:

```
  NSInteger ir1 = 0;
  NSArray * mySecondArray =[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"$ 120", @"$ 22", @"$ 20", @"$ 10", @"$ 11", @"$ 0", @"$ 1234", @"$ 3333", nil];

  for (int k =0; k<mySecondArray.count; k++) {
             NSString *rest = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[mySecondArray objectAtIndex:k]];
        NSString* noSpaces =  [rest stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"$" withString:@""];
        ir1 = ir1 +[noSpaces integerValue];
 }


 NSInteger    Sum = ir + ir1 ;
 NSLog(@"myFirstArray :: %ld",(long)ir);
 NSLog(@"mySecondArray :: %ld",(long)ir1);
 NSLog(@"Sum :: %ld",(long)Sum);
```

> console:
>
> myFirstArray :: 1610
>
> mySecondArray :: 4750
>
> Sum :: 6360

Comment: This is really great, thank you so much. The main reason to doing this is that I am using didRegionChanged in MKMapView to count title annotations displayed which are the prices.

Comment: @tomasfn glad this helped you..Please accept the answer if this has solved your issue..

Answer (score 2):

The definition of your array seems messy. Is it from JSON?

If YES:

```
-(NSInteger)sumJSONArrayStr:(NSString *)jsonStr
{
    NSArray *array = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:[jsonStr dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] options:0 error:nil];
    NSMutableArray *cleanAndFlatenArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    NSMutableCharacterSet *charSet = [NSMutableCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"$"];
    [charSet formUnionWithCharacterSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];
    for (NSString *aStr in array)
    {
        NSArray *split = [aStr componentsSeparatedByString:@","];
        for (NSString *aSplit in split)
        {
            [cleanAndFlatenArray addObject:[aSplit stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:charSet]];
        }
    }
    NSNumber *sum = [cleanAndFlatenArray valueForKeyPath:@"@sum.integerValue"];
    return [sum integerValue];
}
```

Call:

```
NSInteger val1 = [self sumJSONArrayStr:@"[\"$ 22, $ 0\", \"$ 33, $ 666, $ 66, $ 22\", \"$ 123, $ 123, $ 555\"]"];
NSInteger val2 = [self sumJSONArrayStr:@"[\"$ 120\", \"$ 22\", \"$ 20\", \"$ 10\", \"$ 11\", \"$ 0\", \"$ 1234\", \"$ 3333\"]"];
```

If not, just consider the flatten method and the removal of the "$" character.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to sum all the numbers inside Array,then first of all by using `stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString` remove all that spaces,commas and $. Then you can do sum of all the number in your array.

for that use following code:

```
NSInteger sum = 0;
for (NSNumber *num in myFirstArray)

{

  sum += [num intValue];
}
```

Do same for second array:

```
    NSInteger sum = 0;
for (NSNumber *num in mySecondArray)

{

  sum += [num intValue];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If your array contains only spaces, commas and '$' characters use the following code for first array

```
int totalPrice = 0;
NSString *tempPrice;
NSArray *tempArray;
for (NSString *multiplePriceString in myFirstArray) {
    tempPrice = [multiplePriceString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""];
    tempPrice = [multiplePriceString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"$" withString:@""];
    tempArray = [tempPrice componentsSeparatedByString:@","];
    for (NSString *price in tempArray) {
        totalPrice = totalPrice + [price intValue];
    }
}
```

For second array use

```
int totalPrice = 0;
NSString *tempPrice;
for (NSString *singlePriceString in myFirstArray) {
    tempPrice = [singlePriceString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""];
    tempPrice = [singlePriceString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"$" withString:@""];
    totalPrice = totalPrice + [singlePriceString intValue];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This code may help you:

```
-(int)totalAmountForArray:(NSArray *)arrayToCalculateAmount{

    float amountToReturn = 0.0;

    for (NSString *aValue in arrayToCalculateAmount)
    {
        NSString *aLocalValue = aValue;
        aLocalValue = [aLocalValue stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:NSMakeRange(0, 2) withString:@""];//adjust range length parameter value according to your requirement.

        amountToReturn = amountToReturn + aLocalValue.intValue;
    }

    return amountToReturn;
}
```